# How can I adjust TextView Hieght, width, and Rotation With dottod line selection

Tags: android, textview

Actually I want to Rotate TextView with rotation mark that stands on the corner of selection

And 6 dots those are appeared on the dotted line selection for Changing height and width

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://effectiveandroid.tumblr.com/post/143176372647/dragging-scaling-rotating-on-april-fools-day)

Comment: @grrigore Awesome but I'm beggner of android development .

Comment: @grrigore I want to style whole code step by step

Comment: I want to share also a image  but stack overflow  says . Reputation